# Spring JPA Projection inside of Projection

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, projection

i have following entities

A.class

```
@Entity
public class A {
   List<B> listOfB;
   //getters and setters
}
```

B.class

```
@Entity
public class B {
   private long id;
   private  List<C> listOfC;
    //getters and setters
}
```

C.class

```
@Entity
public class C {
   long getId();
}
```

In some cases C.class is unnecessary. So I tried to ignore it at the query with projection;

AView.class

```
public interface AView {
   List<BView> getB();
}
```

BView.class

```
public interface BView {
   long getId();
}
```

The JSON Response looks fine, but the Hibernate Query log is showing the SELECT of class C.
I read a custom query at solution. But the Problem is that the classes have too many fields.

Is it posible to ignore the select of c in the query without writing a custom Query?

Answer (score 0):

This seemed like a `FetchType` related issue to me.

If you are providing the relations with spring data jpa annotations, You might consider using `FetchType.LAZY`.

Like : `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

Comment: I don't think so. If I remove  List<BView> getB() from AView.class. The hibernate query log does not request the datafor B.class. I would like to resolve this issue without edititing the  entities